# Elegantly inject pre-rendered element into Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render an existing HTMLElement in a Vue component, like follows:

```js
const someElement = document.createElement('p'); // for instance

Vue.component('my-component', {
  data: () => ({ someElement }),
  template: '<div>{{ someElement }}</div>',
  // The above doesn't work; {{ moustache }} tags turn the element into a string.
});
```

There are several partial solutions, but none are perfect:

1. I could use `v-html`, which will work for some elements, but will fail to preserve e.g. event listeners.

   ```js
   Vue.component('my-component', {
     data: () => ({ someElement }),
     template: '<div v-html="someElement.outerHTML"></div>',
   });
   ```
2. I could manually inject the element on the `mounted()` hook, which will work, but is somewhat ugly and feels unidiomatic.

   ```js
   Vue.component('my-component', {
     data: () => ({ someElement }),
     template: '<div></div>',
     mounted() {
       this.$el.appendChild(someElement);
     },
   });
   ```
3. If I could somehow wrap the element in a component, I could render that wrapper component. But it's unclear how to do this. I could use a [manual `render()` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), but `render()` seems to have to return a `VNode` instance, and I see no way to turn an `HTMLElement` object into a `VNode` instance. A way shouldn't be expected to exist, given that `VNode` represents a virtual DOM whereas `HTMLElement` is part of the actual DOM.

   ```js
   Vue.component('element-wrapper', {
     render() {
       return someElement;  // can't, not a VNode
     },
   });
   Vue.component('my-component', {
     template: '<div><element-wrapper></element-wrapper></div>',
   });
   ```
4. I could use [`:is`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), but `:is` expects a component options object, meaning this option has all the same difficulties as #3.

   ```js
   Vue.component('my-component', {
     template: '<div><component :is="elementAsComponent"></component></div>',
     data: () => ({
       elementAsComponent: /* again need to wrap element in component */,
     }),
   });
   ```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by wrapping the custom element in a very thin Vue component which just replaces its root element with the custom element on mount.

Like so ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4dkvgmj/2/)):

```js
const myCustomElement = document.createElement('p');
myCustomElement.innerText = 'click me';
myCustomElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myCustomElement.style.color = 'red';
})

/* Takes an HTMLElement and returns a wrapping Vue component options object */
function liftToVue(element) {
  return {
    template: '<div></div>',
    mounted() {
        this.$el.replaceWith(element);
    },
    // If element is or may be a Promise, you can do:
    // async mounted() { this.$el.replaceWith(await element); }
  };
}

Vue.component('my-component', {
  data: () => ({ myCustomElementAsComponent: liftToVue(myCustomElement) }),
  template: '<div><component :is="myCustomElementAsComponent" /></div>',
})
```

---

There is a high chance, however, that this is [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). See if you can use Vue components in the first place instead of generating `HTMLElement` instances at all.