# Render an existing HTMLElement within a vue3 template

Tags: vue.js, three.js, vuejs3

Let's say I have an existing htmlElement:
`const myElement = document.createElement('DIV');`, I would like this instance to be renderer within a vue3 template.

Using composition API, it would look like something like:

```
<template>
     <MyElement></myElement>
</template>
<script setup>
   const MyElement = document.createElement('DIV');
</script>
```

Does somebody knows if I could achieve something like that ?

My concrete need is about using threejs with vue3 this way:

```
<template>
     <renderer.domElement></renderer.domElement>
</template>
<script setup>
   import { WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
   const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
   [...]
</script>
```

instead of doing something like:

```
<template>
     <canvas ref="canvasRef"></canvas>
</template>
<script setup>
   import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
   import { WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
   const canvasRef = ref(null);
   const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
   onMounted(async () => {
  const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvasRef.value as HTMLCanvasElement,
  });
});
</script>
```

-> As the WebGLRenderer instance already contains an existing HTMLCanvasElement (`renderer.domElement`), it would be extremely usefull in my case if the renderer could be declared before the component is mounted !

I have tried jsx/render functions, I am currently looking at vue3 custom renderer (but I am not sure overloading the existing renderer is the good solution...)

Comment: Have tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67918532/8172857?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thank you. Actually, unless I missed something, it wouldn't exactly allow to use an existing HTMLElement instance, but would create a new one instead. Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

For injecting elements, you can use `v-html` or any of the discussed ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730897/elegantly-inject-pre-rendered-element-into-vue-template).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. V-html does not actually do the job as it creates a new instance. Appendchild would eventually but I need a parent element (i don t have it)

Comment: No problem man :) 
You can wrap `MyElement` with a div or an empty Vue component -> This way you'd have a parent element. You can then use appendChild to the wrapper component and you should be good to go.

Comment: Again, thanks. Your right, and I have indeed created this wrapping div for now as a dirty fix, but I want to avoid adding unecessary DOM elements just because of some Vuejs limitations. The spirit is: "Vue is serving me", not "me serving vue" :-)